# Rails 3.2 update action with Ajax.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a update form using Ajax for a Rails 3.2 app. I'm a Ajax beginner so I need some guidance. What I want to achieve is:

```
1. The user presses a button and a form slides down from the top in a div. 
2. The user updates the form and presses "update".
3. The parameters from the updated form is sent and saved to the database, and 
4. the form slides up again without making the user leave the page.
```

The form currently looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <%= f.fields_for :oak do |oak| %>
    <%= oak.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :energy_meter do |energy_meter| %>
    <%= energy_meter.text_field :energy_meter_id, :placeholder => "Id" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Update!", "data-role" => "button", "data-theme" => "b", "return" => "false" %>
<% end %>
```

I have a update action that currently looks like this:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
end
```

It is located in my UsersController.

I also have a update.js.erb file that currently looks like this:

```
$(window.location.replace("/"))
```

I don't know what I should put update.js.erb to do what I want, nor how to send the parameters, it currently only redirects to  `/`. I also wonder where and what I should put in my update action, it is currently located in UsersController, but should it be located in my PagesController where my form is located?

Any tips or guidance would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add following code to `aaplication.js`

```
$("#BUTTON_ELEMENT").live("click", function() {
    $("#FORM_ELEMENT").slideDown();
});

$("#FORM_ELEMENT").live("submit", function() {
    var _form = $(this);
    $.post(_form.attr("action"), _form.serialize(), function() { _form.slideUp(); }, "script");
    return false;
});
```

For testing purpose add some alert to `update.js.erb`

Comment: Hi, have got the alert to show up. But it the redirects to /users/1. My update action currently looks like this: `def update @user = current_user respond_to do |format| @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) format.js { render :layout => false } end end`. And the text undefined is displayed.

Comment: make sure you've given correct `form id` in `application.js` also check on console which request (i.e. JS or HTML) is being sent when form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `respond_to` block to the controller and add a `format.js` so that the controller will then render the `update.js.erb` file.

You don't need this line:

```
$(window.location.replace("/"))
```

By default, the URL doesn't change upon an `AJAX` call.

Comment: For some reason is does redirect, to /users/1. Thats why I added the above line. I don't know how to make it not redirect to that url, it seems like it render my update.js.erb file.

Comment: I think adding `event.preventDefault()` on the button/link might prevent it from redirecting to `/users/1`.  See: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this applies to this case but if this is like making a search field using jquery... i think you should put this code in update.js.erb?

```
$('#DIV_ID').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("update")) %>');
```

Where "update" is an _update.html.erb file containing the form and "#DIV_ID" is the div where you want the form to be rendered.

Maybe this railscast can help explain it better than i do, hope it helps.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?autoplay=true